Number of unique paths in a grid
Suppose, I have a nxn grid. Now, I want to move from (1,1) to (1,n). How many unique ways are there possible if I can move in left, right, up and down direction.
I am trying to solve it using depth first search.
int dp[N+1][N+1];
int vis[N+1][N+1];

int dirx[4] = {1, -1, 0, 0};
int diry[4] = {0, 0, 1, -1};

int fun(int i, int j){
    if(i == N && j == 0) return dp[i][j] = 1;
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>N || j>N) return 0;
    if(vis[i][j]) return dp[i][j];
    vis[i][j] = 1;
    int ret = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k<4; k++){
        int x = i+dirx[k], y = j+diry[k];
        ret += fun(x, y);
    }
    return dp[i][j] = ret;
}

But, I think there is a problem. Suppose, I have reached (n-1, 2) then I need the value of (n-1, 1). dp[n-1][1] depends on dp[n-1][2], to stop running back and forth I have set vis[n-1][2] as 1, which is not correct at all. How can I solve this problem?
To be more specific, we can visit a cell at most once. Hence, there is no cycle in the path.
What is the time complexity of  this problem? Is it O(4^n)? What is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

I don't think dynamic programming is useful in this instance since there is no way (in that case) to know if all unique paths leading to the cell $(n-1, n)$ have not already been through $(n-1, 2)$ already (thereby creating an infinite loop, if so).

If we can move in right, down direction only then there is no loop and we can solve this easily. What about the  case when we can move in all 4 direction? What would be the time complexity for solving this problem. Here, n <10. @ZiadIsmailiAlaoui

These numbers become huge. As a reference:  https://oeis.org/A271507 "Number of self-avoiding walks of any length from NW to SW corners on an n X n grid or lattice".

Is it possible to calculate it in exponential time complexity or less. Suppose, to avoid integer overflow, we take mod 1e9+7.@HendrikJan

I understand you are not looking for shortest paths, but I think more precision is needed on what it is you call "unique ways": paths that go through each node at most once? through each link at most once? are the paths allowed to go backwards in the grid?

Yes, going through each node at most once and it can move in any 4 directions. Since, it is not allowed to visit a node more than once, hence there is no cycle in the path.@MatthieuLatapy


Please don't reply in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the post.  Please don't append "Edit: [clarifications]".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and incorporate all relevant information into the question at the appropriate point in the logical flow.  2. What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking for any algorithm at all for this problem?  Do you require it to use DFS?  Do you require the algorithm to run in polynomial time?


If we assume we do not repeat any vertex, the required count is finite. Here is one possible way to solve this. Consider the grid as a graph, and try to find the number of $k$-length paths for all $n\le k \le n^2$. See here for a convinient way to find the number of $k$-length paths in a graph.
See here for a dynamic programming solution for a similar, but more restricted case.

The second link only allows up and right movements.

Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer
